# how to make css div margin-top 20px from div above

Tags: css

I have this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/kc94aq33/

i want to have the `.wrapper` top margin 20px from the bottom of the `.header`

how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated the CSS on you JS Fiddle, the code used is below

```
.header {
    width:550px;
    margin:20px auto 20px auto;
}
.header:after{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

When ever you are using floating containers you should always use a clearfix

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's breaking is because the elements in your header is floating *left* and *right*. If all the elements are floating *left/right* the parent container (in this case the header) will collapse to `0px` or to the height of the element that's **not** floating; There are a number of ways to fix this.

I prefer the following - reusable way.

Create a class "*clearfix*" that you can reuse on elements with floating children.

```
.clearfix:before, 
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Add the "*clearfix*" class to the header element and voila! The  element will "self clear".

For example:

```
<div class="header clearfix">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="" width="240px" />
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <h1>Control Panel</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="login_text"></h1>
        <form>...</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This cause of unclose floating element.
you can add css something like this

`.clear {clear:both;}
.header {margin-bottom:20px;}`

and add `<div class="clear"></div>`

right after your close tag div `"right"`

i'm update your fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/kc94aq33/2/